# Agenda js: what happens if my server is down on the scheduled time of a job?

Tags: node.js, job-scheduling, agenda

Lets say I have a job scheduled using [@agenda/agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) like this

```
agenda.schedule('tomorrow at noon', 'printAnalyticsReport', {userCount: 100});
```

I wonder what will happen if my server/node script os down?

- Is agenda is able to restart the past job on next server restart?
- If not, how can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** and **no**. Agenda should pick your jobs if it was shutdown `gracefuly`.

What that means is that if all goes well the actual jobs `lockedAt` field would not be set (will be `null`) which should expose your stale jobs for pickup.

However if there was NOT a graceful shutdown then they will be skipped since as far as agenda is concerned they are still running.

In situations like this where jobs are in `limbo` mode the [UI tool for agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agendash) is extremely helpful. It shows you all the jobs running and gives you a very good overview of what is happening so after a restart you can always review and address any issues.

Another approach would be to run a script the unlock all locked jobs on server start:

```
db.agendaJobs.update({}, {$set: {lockedAt: null}});
```

Or a little more precise way to achieve the same result with [this method.](https://github.com/agenda/agenda/issues/410#issuecomment-310526028)

Or another somewhat clean way to do this can be found [here](https://github.com/Trustroots/trustroots/blob/master/config/lib/worker.js#L175-L228).

Here is more on the [Agenda stop](https://github.com/agenda/agenda#stop)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the db update is the method I planned based on the initial research.